# App Hangs on Splash Screen on device but loads fine on simulator

Tags: screen, ios11, xcode9

Hi i had spend the last 12 hours fighting with this, the app loads on simulator iOS 11.3 but no on my device iPhone 6s Plus iOS 11.2 it hangs on the splash screen forever, i call the initial view with this code: ` self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nac"];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`
```

And tried to load the initial view from the Project settings and nothing,

On the log it shows this: 2018-05-04 17:35:08.822190-0400 AppF[1480:388349] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework

I have the Provisioning profiles set to auto.